# UWP Semantic zoom

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10

I have semantic zoom.

```
<SemanticZoom 
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="1" ViewChangeStarted="SemanticZoom_ViewChangeStarted">
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
            <ListView 
                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush}" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"
                SelectionMode="None" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="{ThemeResource AccentBrush}" FontSize="{ThemeResource HubHeaderThemeFontSize}" Text="{Binding Key}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
            <GridView 
                Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush}" 
                x:Name="MainCollection" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"
                ItemClick="MainCollection_ItemClick"
                IsItemClickEnabled="True"               
                SelectionMode="None">
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:TileApp">
                        <Grid Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Source="{x:Bind Medium, Converter={StaticResource LinkConverter}}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="350" x:Name="Name" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Bind AppName}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                            <FontIcon Grid.Column="2" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE840;" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <GridView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="{ThemeResource AccentBrush}" Text="{Binding Key}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </GridView.GroupStyle>
            </GridView>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
    </SemanticZoom>
```

And here's my grouping

```
var groups = from c in TilesCollection
                     group c by c.Category into g
                     orderby g.Key
                     select g;
        this.cvs.Source = groups;
```

The problem is that when I press on the header. ZoomOutView does not display them. I see nothing. But if you click in a place where there should be the headlines, it moves to the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XAML, the ListView and TextBlock bindings are not correct

```
<SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
    <!-- So I've removed ItemsSource property on the ListView in XAML -->
    <!-- And added a name to it -->
    <ListView x:Name="ZoomoutCollection"
            Margin="0,0,0,0"
            Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush}" 
            SelectionMode="None" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="{ThemeResource AccentBrush}" FontSize="{ThemeResource HubHeaderThemeFontSize}" Text="{Binding Group.Key}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
```

And you need to add this extra line in C# (code behind) as I've removed the ListView binding in XAML

```
var groups = from c in TilesCollection
                 group c by c.Category into g
                 orderby g.Key
                 select g;
this.cvs.Source = groups;
// And moved ItemsSource here, since we need a more complex binding
// Note that 'ZoomoutCollection' is the new named ListView
ZoomoutCollection.ItemsSource = this.cvs.View.CollectionGroups;
```